# SQL Server: fill a column with random decimal numbers

Tags: sql-server-2008

i want my function to generate float numbers ( like : -123.000 , 874.000 ) in range ( like between: 272 and 3357 ) and update every record's *"pos_x"* field with unique float numbers.
I write this Code but i see my table's field are all identical and also integer and they are positive.

this is my code :

```
UPDATE Driver_tbl
SET pos_x = (ROUND((RAND()* 10000),0))
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

RAND is evaluated *once* per query

You can seed it like this though using `CHECKSUM(NEWID())` so it is random *per row*

```
UPDATE Driver_tbl
SET pos_x = ROUND(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * (3357-272),0) + 272
```

However, you can also cut out the middle man if you are using ROUND(.., 0)

```
UPDATE Driver_tbl
SET pos_x = ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 9999
```

Comment: @rN uǝɹɐ: no, this is all you need

Comment: what if i wanted to generate in range?

Comment: for exp: generate float numbers between 272.000 and 3357.000